# Find missing columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables of the following structure:

**1. City_Details:**
This table consists of all the applicable tables and columns for each city.

```
Country_Name    City_Name   Table_Name  Column_Name
USA             New York    T1          T1C1
USA             New York    T1          T1C2
USA             New York    T1          T1C3
USA             New York    T2          T2C1
USA             Los Angeles T2          T2C1
USA             Los Angeles T2          T2C2
USA             Los Angeles T2          T2C3
England         London      T1          T1C1
England         London      T3          T3C1
England         London      T3          T3C2
```

**2. Max_Column_Details**: This table consists the information about all the tables that CAN exist for each city and the maximum columns that each table CAN have.

```
Table_Name  Column_Name
T1          T1C1
T1          T1C2
T1          T1C3
T1          T1C4
T2          T2C1
T2          T2C2
T2          T2C3
T2          T2C4
T2          T2C5
T2          T2C6
T3          T3C1
T3          T3C2
T3          T3C3
T4          T4C1
T4          T4C2
```

I want to write an SQL query that returns the missing columns only for the tables PRESENT in each city. For example, New York has T1 with 3 column T1C1, T1C2, T1C3.
T1 can have maximum four columns, namely T1C1, T1C2, T1C3, T1C4. So, the missing column for table T1 in New York is T1C4. Similarly the missing column for other tables for other cities is needed. So the resultant should be as under:

```
Country_Code    City_Code   Table_Name  Column_Name
USA             New York    T1          T1C4
USA             New York    T2          T2C2
USA             New York    T2          T2C3
USA             New York    T2          T2C4
USA             New York    T2          T2C5
USA             New York    T2          T2C6
USA             Los Angeles T2          T2C4
USA             Los Angeles T2          T2C5
USA             Los Angeles T2          T2C6
England         London      T1          T1C2
England         London      T1          T1C3
England         London      T1          T1C4
England         London      T3          T3C3
```

I tried some queries using MINUS, EXCEPT, EXIST and NOT EXIST, but still I am not able to get the rquired result. I am not so proficient in SQL. Please help.

Comment: Did you try anything? Please include your SQL and also the result you get.

Comment: @LutzHorn Yes. I tried the following but did not work. SELECT DISTINCT Country_Name, City_Name, Table_Name, Column_Name FROM City_Details WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Max_Column_Details WHERE City_Details.table_name = Max_Column_Details.table_name and City_Details.column_name = Max_Column_Details.column_name) minus (SELECT * FROM City_Details) order by 1,2,3;

Comment: Please edit your question to include the SQL. Don't put code into a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with ct as (select distinct Country_Name, City_Name, Table_Name
             from City_Details)
select ct.Country_Name, ct.City_Name, m.Column_name 
  from ct, Max_Column_Details m
  where ct.Table_Name = m.Table_Name
    and not exists ( select 1 from City_Details
                       where Country_Name = ct.Country_Name
                         and City_Name = ct.City_Name
                         and Table_Name = ct.Table_Name
                         and Column_Name = m.Column_Name )
  order by 1, 2, 3;
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks. this really did the trick. But can you explain what exactly have we done here?

Comment: Sorry. I am unable to upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Doesn't matter, accepting the answer also gives mit 15 rep points. What have we done here: The first line (`with...`) makes the subquery available as `ct`, so we know which cities use which tables. This is joined with Max_Column_Details (as an oldfashioned hardcore Oracle user, I usually do not use the JOIN keyword, call it a bad habit if you want) and then a subquery is used to find out which possible combinations are missing.

Comment: but i didn't understand the purpose of "select 1 from City_Details"

Comment: The `1` is meaningless in an `exists` subquery, many people write `*` instead for exactly the same effect. The subquery itself filters out the already existing entries, so you only get the missing ones.

Comment: Also, why did we require 
"`where Country_Name = ct.Country_Name
       and City_Name = ct.City_Name
       and Table_Name = ct.Table_Name`" 
when we only required column comparision. I tried to do the column comparision but it gave an empty result set.

Comment: We need to compare that other columns (Country_Name, City_name, Table_Name) too, because otherwise, we would just check if the Column_name is used anywhere at all, regardless of (Country_Name, City_name, Table_Name).